# Not able to understand the output of javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am getting **5** as the output of following code

```js
function myfunction1(){
   number = 5;
}

function myfunction(number){
  number = number + 10;
}

myfunction1();
myfunction(number);

console.log(number);
```

I expected to throw a reference error for **number**. It would be great if someone can explain the behavior.thanks in advance

Comment: `number = 5;` you have created a global variable here, in none strict mode it will work.  But in strict, you will get undefined.  And this `number = number + 10;` is a NoOP, as you don't return the value.  And it won't effect the global either, as you have it as a parameter.

Comment: thanks @Keith. Now it is clear to me

Answer (score 2):

By never declaring `number`, the javascript interpreter is evaluating `number` as global variable.

If you do:

```js
function myfunction1(){
   var number = 5;
}

function myfunction(number){
  number = number + 10;
}

myfunction1();
myfunction(number);

console.log(number);
```

This should throw you an error, since now, `number=5` is only true inside `myfunction1`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have same names for global variable and function argument you are assigning to an argument.

This should work.

```js
let number;

function myfunction1(){
  number = 5;
}

function myfunction(n){
 number = n + 10;
}

myfunction1();
myfunction(number);

console.log(number);
```